# How can I parse a csv file to apache hbase in a table?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hbase

I'm new to Apache Hbase and I need to parse a csv file with values to a table in HBase

The below code is what I have tried:

```
public class HBaseDataInsert
{ 
    Configuration conf; 
    HTable hTable; 
    HBaseScan hbaseScan;

    public HBaseDataInsert() throws IOException
    {
        conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        hTable = new HTable(conf, "emp_java");
    }

    public void upload_transactionFile() throws IOException 
    {

        String currentLine = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("transactionsFile.csv"));
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(currentLine);
            String[] line = currentLine.split(",");
            Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(line[0] + "_" + line[1]));
            p.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("Name"), Bytes.toBytes(line[0]));
            p.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("id"), Bytes.toBytes(line[1]));
            p.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("DATE"), Bytes.toBytes(line[2]));
            p.add(Bytes.toBytes("transaction details"), Bytes.toBytes("TRANSACTION_TYPE"), Bytes.toBytes(line[3]));

            hTable.put(p);
       }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> /tmp/java_D5BSep/HBaseDataInsert.java:24: error: reached end of file
>   while parsing }

Comment: What is the error you've got?

Comment: /tmp/java_D5BSep/HBaseDataInsert.java:24: error: reached end of file while parsing
}

Comment: Can you debug the code and see values assigned to `currentLine` before it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `"}"` for your main class. Please add it at the end and check.